# Changing ItemName (primary key) in SimpleDB with boto

Tags: python, boto, amazon-simpledb

I would like to modify ItemNames in my SimpleDB using boto. While I have been able to change attributes easily using the item['attr'] = xxxxxx, I have not been able to figure out how to change the ItemNames themselves. My failed attempt is shown below. Any guidance would be much appreciated.

```
connection = boto.connect_sdb(ACCESS_KEY,SECRET_KEY)
domain = connection.get_domain(domain_name)
new_unique_name = 'MyNewPrimaryKey'
item = domain.get_item('CurrentPrimaryKey')
item.name = new_unique_name
item.save
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can not change the `itemName()`. `Amazon SimpleDB` simply requires a unique identifier for each row in your database. `Item` Name should be unique like your `pk` in your traditional database. You can not update the itemName(). You can delete it and again create it with your new name. Please remember, if you delete `itemName()`then all `attribute-value` pair that are associate with that `itemName()` will also delete.

Comment: Thank you Ashish. I want to change to a new naming pattern for the ItemNames so I will recreate them and delete the old records since the ItemNames can not be modified.